# Run function that is inside of jquery .on('change')

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to run a function that is inside of a Jquery `.on('change')`.
 The reason is that i want this function to load when a select changes, and when the page loads.
Yeah

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Load function on pageload
  sum();

  //Load function on 'change'
  $('.ChooseMonth').on('change', function sum(){
     console.log('Loaded');
  });
```

This code won´t work when page loads..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it prettier to move your logic:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Load function on pageload
  sum();

  //Load function on 'change'
  $('.ChooseMonth').on('change', sum);

function sum(){
     console.log('Loaded');
  });
```

Comment: Yes, i will use this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> *NO*, As `sum` is not under the global scope hence it will throw error `Uncaught ReferenceError: sum is not defined`

There are few workarounds for this:

**1)** Create another function and execute it. Also pass the same function as handler for change listener.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sum = function() {
    snippet.log('Loaded');
  };
  sum();
  $('.ChooseMonth').on('change', sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class='ChooseMonth'>
```

**2)** [`trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) change event, this will as as `change` event over `input element` is invoked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ChooseMonth').on('change', function() {
    snippet.log('Loaded');
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class='ChooseMonth'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do invoke the change event once the DOM got ready,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ChooseMonth').on('change', function{
     console.log('Loaded');
  }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at it wrong, don't run the function that's inside a change listener, call a function on change, that can also be called at other times:

```
var myFunc = function() {
  //do something
}


$('.ChooseMonth').change(function(e) { myFunc(); });

myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ChooseMonth').change(Your_function_name_goes_here);
```